# Echo message when flag is detected

Tags: bash, echo

This works well at running Seamonkey only once per 24 hours.

I would like to show a message if the flag is detected.

I am not sure where to put that echo statement.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#  Run this script only once a day
#  Delay is necessary

# Creates this file /var/tmp/SeaAfter5.sh.flag
flag="/var/tmp/$(basename -- $0).flag"
min_age=$(( 60 * 60 * 24 )) # 24 hours

if [ -e "$flag" ] ;then
  (( $(date +%s) - $(date +%s -r "$flag") > min_age )) || exit 1
fi
touch "$flag"

# Proceed with starting Seamonkey
sleep 5 && seamonkey
```

Modified some posted code by icarus. When run it says no flag file and does not run Seamonkey

```
if [ -e "$flag" ] ;then
  if (( $(date +%s) - $(date +%s -r "$flag") > min_age ));then
     echo "Seamonkey starting in 5 seconds."
     # Proceed with starting Seamonkey
sleep 5 && seamonkey

  else
     echo "Seamonkey has already been run today."
     exit 1
  fi
else
  echo "No flag file detected"
fi
```

Comment: What have you tried? How did it differ from expectations or intentions?

Comment: Do you want a message when the flag file *exists* or when the file's timestamp is too young to invoke seamonkey again?

Comment: When the file's timestamp is too young to invoke seamonkey again. @Sotto Voce

Comment: @fixit7 *"When run it says no flag file and does not run Seamonkey"*  If you get that is because your flag file doesn't exist. Make sure you have that file (or create it) and run the script again.

Comment: My code was to replace the 3 lines in the middle of the script, not the whole script! The code you have altered has changed the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is:

```
if [ -e "$flag" ] ;then
  (( $(date +%s) - $(date +%s -r "$flag") > min_age )) || exit 1
fi
```

I would convert the middle line into three:

```
if [ -e "$flag" ] ;then
  (( $(date +%s) - $(date +%s -r "$flag") > min_age )) || {
    echo "Flag file \"$flag\" is not old enough to invoke seamonkey yet"
    exit 1
  }
fi
```

There are a number of other things you can do with the message (like give the file's age in seconds) if you use separate statements to get the current timestamp, the file's timestamp, and the difference, rather than packing them together into a single statement.  But that would make for more lines in the script and you might not want that.

Comment: In all the code that has been posted, there is no provision for sleep 5 && seamonkey and it does not create a flag. I think touch "$flag" is necessary.

Comment: What are you looking for?  I didn't replace your whole script, just expanded 3 lines in the middle into 5 lines.  The lines before and after, where the `flag` and `min_age` variables receive their values, and the `touch`, `sleep`, and `seamonkey` commands, would still be in the script.

Comment: Thanks so much. It is now working. @Sotto Voce

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking. Hopefully this will enable you to answer your own question. You need to change the

```
if [ -e "$flag" ] ;then
  (( $(date +%s) - $(date +%s -r "$flag") > min_age )) || exit 1
fi
```

to something like

```
if [ -e "$flag" ] ;then
  if (( $(date +%s) - $(date +%s -r "$flag") > min_age ));then
     echo "We need to run seamonkey"
  else
     echo "No need to run seamonkey"
     exit 1
  fi
else
  echo "No flag file detected"
fi
```

Comment: I modified your code and added it to my post with some comments. @icarus

Comment: @fixit7 The reason why I expanded the OP's code from shortcuts to if/then/else/fi was to allow arbitrary statements without needing to worry about their return values.  It allowed the OP to handle all 3 cases, the flag file not existing, the flag file being less than a day old and the flag file being more than a day old.